# How to retrieve data from selected row in gridview inside ModalPopUp dialog and then close after in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to retrieve data when selecting a row in gridview using asp.net.

I have gridview inside ModalPopUp dialog that pop-ups whenever the user clicks the button "Browse". The gridview was populated by data from database. The first column was a Button field named "Select", so everytime the user clicks the button from specific row the data on the first index must be displayed inside a textbox, and the ModalPopUp dialog must be closed.

I tried below codes on retrieving the data from selected row and closing or hiding the ModalPopUp dialog after clicking button field inside gridview but it doesn't work.

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then

        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow

        txttitle.Text = row.Cells(1).Text

        mdlpopup.Hide()

    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as like,

```
 txttitle.Text = DirectCast(row.Cells(1).FindControl("TxtboxID"),TextBox).Text
```